# .htaccess deny dot-files but allow letsencrypt

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

My goal is to deny access to all dot-files e.g `.htaccess`, `.env` and send back a 404, but allow the letsencrypt-folder `.well-known` to be accessed

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "(^|/)\.(?!well-known)" - [F]
RedirectMatch 404 /\..*$
```

Any hint on how to achieve this is highly appreciated
Best endo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (?:^|/)\.[^/]+$ - [R=404]
```

This will serve a 404 for any *file* (or rather, last URL-path segment) that starts with a dot. But it will permit `.well-known/` - since this is a directory and so is also suffixed by at least a slash + filename.

**UPDATE:** Modified regex so that it matches the dot at the start of the last path-segment, rather than anywhere in the last path-segment!

Note that the `F` flag responds with a 403 Forbidden, not a 404 as requested.

---

Alternatively, you can use a `<Files>` (or `<FilesMatch>`) container, which only matches "files". For example:

```
<Files ".*">
    # 404 Not Found
    Redirect 404 /

    # OR... 403 Forbidden
    #Require all denied
</Files>
```

Although this does also block a request for `/.well-known` (no trailing slash) - although that's not strictly a valid request anyway.

Comment: This is a quite elegant way, thx

Comment: @endo.anaconda Actually there was a "bug" in the regex as it would have matched a dot _anywhere_ in the last path segment, not just at the start. eg. `/some.thing` would have also been blocked! I've updated my answer (improved regex). I've also added an alternative solution using a `<Files>` container.